# wating for response from consumer in rabitmq and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, microservices

I have two project with nodejs and typescript and a want to start comunication with rabitmq .

i install `amqplib` library from npm and use this config for published and subscriber project :

import amqp from 'amqplib';

```
export class MessageBroker {

    private static channel: amqp.Channel;

    public static async Initial(exchange: string, queue: string) {

        let cluster = await amqp.connect('amqps://mcbzjnsn:0hHb-M1u_XwvuyYch3fM9vJOQUaVBmPQ@cow.rmq2.cloudamqp.com/mcbzjnsn');
        let channel = await cluster.createChannel();

        await channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'direct', { durable: true, autoDelete: true });

        await channel.assertQueue(queue + '.' + exchange, {
            exclusive: true
        });

        await channel.bindQueue(queue + '.' + exchange, exchange, queue);

        channel.prefetch(1);

        this.channel = channel;

    }

    //Random id generator
    private static randomid() {
        return new Date().getTime().toString() + Math.random().toString() + Math.random().toString();
    }
    static async Publish(exchange: string, queue: string, message: any): Promise<void> {

        let id = this.randomid();

        MessageBroker.channel.sendToQueue(exchange, queue,
            Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message)), { correlationId: id, replyTo: 'amq.rabbitmq.reply-to' })

    }

    static async SendToQueue(queue: string, message: any): Promise<void> {

        let id = this.randomid();

        MessageBroker.channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from('10'), {
            correlationId: id,
            replyTo: queue
        });
    }

    private static async Consume(exchange: string, queue: string): Promise<void> {



    }


}
```

now i want to use send message from project A to Project B with this code :

```
await MessageBroker.Publish('coin', 'transaction',{
            type:MessageBrokerType.Transfer,
            to:'0x36f5C37B48c7888634b9285ae30eeACa5AD427C0',
            amount:100
        });
```

and I need wait to projectB response but it does not wait for response from projectB and go the next line.

now, how can I do it? ( wait for response from the result of project B )

Comment: As far as I remember its hardly possible because your message is just put to the queue, which ends the responsibility of message broker. So you can't know if the message was processed etc.

Comment: @NikitaMazur ok . how can i handle this process manual ?

Comment: Depends on what you want, if you want to know the message was processed, you can create another queue, and send "on process complete" messages there. If you want to wait for response, then message brokers are not what you want and I would suggest using REST instead